# What's the simplest way to figure out the bonjour name of devices in a local network?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, bonjour

the question says it all.

Can someone please tell me if that is possible and how?

I already have the IP Addresses and the MAC Addresses of the devices I want the bonjour name from...

Comment: Not sure if this tutorial helps or not ... it queries but for a specific service that's offered by other devices.  http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/

Comment: Not really. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for machines in the .local domain and your mDNS server listens on the default reserved IP of `224.0.0.251`, port 5353 you can perform a reverse lookup with *dig* in the same way you'd refer to a unicast hostname:

```
dig -x 192.168.1.12 @224.0.0.251 -p 5353
```

Where `192.168.1.12` is the IP you want to check out.